# Certificar PDF com Java

Tags: pdf, java

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de GED(Gestão Eletrônica de Documentos) em Java Web. Nesse sistema necessito ter uma funcionalidade de certificar PDF, no qual será utilizado o certificado do modelo A3. Não tenho ideia de como fazer isto. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Explique melhor o problema. Você já pesquisou alguma coisa? O que é esse "certificado do modelo A3"?

Comment: Pesquisei mas não consegui nenhum esclarecimento. É o seguinte... Para que um arquivo digital tenha valor legal, ele necessita ser assinado digitalmente. Essa assinatura provém do certificado digital. Este certificado possui alguns modelos, o A3 é chamado também de token, no qual ele se parece com um pen-drive. Preciso criar uma funcionalidade no sistema que consiga acessar o certificado, pegar a sua chave e assinar o documento.